# Does case-switch work like this?

Tags: c++, c

I came across a case-switch piece of code today and was a bit surprised to see how it worked. The code was:

```
switch (blah)
{
case a:
  break;
case b:
  break;
case c:
case d:
case e: 
  {
    /* code here */
  }
  break;
default :
  return;
}
```

To my surprise in the scenario where the variable was `c`, the path went inside the "code here" segment. I agree there is no break at the end of the `c` part of the case switch, but I would have imagined it to go through `default` instead. When you land at a `case blah:` line, doesn't it check  if your current value matches the particular case **and only then** let you in the specific segment? Otherwise what's the point of having a case?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

This is called case fall-through, and is a desirable behavior.  It allows you to share code between cases.

An example of how to use case fall-through behavior:

```
switch(blah)
{
case a:
  function1();
case b:
  function2();
case c:
  function3();
  break;
default:
  break;
}
```

If you enter the switch when `blah == a`, then you will execute `function1()`, `function2()`, and `function3()`.

If you don't want to have this behavior, you can opt out of it by including `break` statements.

```
switch(blah)
{
case a:
  function1();
  break;
case b:
  function2();
  break;
case c:
  function3();
  break;
default:
  break;
}
```

The way a switch statement works is that it will (more or less) execute a `goto` to jump to your case label, and keep running from that point.  When the execution hits a `break`, it leaves the switch block.

Comment: :-Thanks for the elaborate reply! I do get how it works .It's just that its against what common sense dictates to me .I still think the behavior is counter-intuitive.I have till date thought that those "case (blah)" was kind of like a check to ensure if your variable indeed is  (blah) ..apparently that's not how C works !

Comment: @Manish: Switch is often implemented with a "[branch table](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Branch_table)", so that might help your understanding too.  Common sense doesn't exist in programming, BTW.  You need "programmer sense" instead :)

Comment: @Manish Both behaviours are desirable, one can either have default fall-through and explicitly `break` out, or default break-out and explicitly `continue` to the next case if desired. From a common sense perspective, the latter may seem more natural, but with the implementation in mind, default fall-through is more natural, so that was chosen.

Answer (score 10):

That is the correct behavior, and it is referred to as "falling through". This lets you have multiple cases handled by the same code. In advanced situations, you may want to perform some code in one case, then fall through to another case.

Contrived example:

```
switch(command)
{
   case CMD_SAVEAS:
   {
      this->PromptForFilename();
   } // DO NOT BREAK, we still want to save
   case CMD_SAVE:
   {
      this->Save();
   } break;


   case CMD_CLOSE:
   {
      this->Close();
   } break;

   default:
      break;
}
```

Comment: The famous example of fall through is [Duff's device](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Duff%27s_device).

Comment: That's a pretty cool usage, but I imagine that's something the compiler will usually do for you when you optimize for speed. I would never want to see that written out in C unless there was a REALLY good reason and an appropriate comment block explaining why it's necessary and how to maintain it.

Answer (score 4):

This is called a fall-through.

It is exactly doing what you are seeing: several cases is going to execute same piece of code.

It is also convenient in doing extra processing for certain case, and some shared logic:

```
// psuedo code:
void stopServer() {
    switch (serverStatus)
    case STARTING:
    {
        extraCleanUpForStartingServer();
        // fall-thru
    }
    case STARTED:
    {
        deallocateResources();
        serverStatus = STOPPED;
        break;
    }
    case STOPPING:
    case STOPPED:
    default:
        // ignored
        break;
}
```

This is a typical use of fall-through in switch-case.  In case of STARTING and STARTED, we need to do deallocateResources and change the status to STOPPED, but STARTING need some extra cleanup.  By the above way, you can clearly present the 'common logic' plus extra logic in STARTING.

STOPPED, STOPPING and default are similar, all of them fall thru to default logic (which is ignoring).

It is not always a good way to code like this but if it is well used it can present the logic better.

Answer (score 2):

Luckily for us, C++ doesn't depend on your imagination :-)

Think of the switch labels as "goto" labels, and the `switch(blah)` simply "goes to" the corresponding label, and then the code just flows from there.

Answer (score 2):

Actually the switch statement works the way you observed.  It is designed so that you can combine several cases together until a break is encountered and it acts something like a sieve.

Here is a real-world example from one of my projects:

```
struct keystore_entry *new_keystore(p_rsd_t rsd, enum keystore_entry_type type, const void *value, size_t size) {
        struct keystore_entry *e;
        e = rsd_malloc(rsd, sizeof(struct keystore_entry));
        if ( !e ) 
                return NULL;
        e->type = type;
        switch (e->type) {
        case KE_DOUBLE:
                memcpy(&e->dblval, value, sizeof(double));
                break;
        case KE_INTEGER:
                memcpy(&e->intval, value, sizeof(int));
                break;

        /* NOTICE HERE */

        case KE_STRING:
                if ( size == 0 ) { 
                        /* calculate the size if it's zero */
                        size = strlen((const char *)value);
                }
        case KE_VOIDPTR:
                e->ptr = rsd_malloc(rsd, size);
                e->size = size;
                memcpy(e->ptr, value, size);
                break;

        /* TO HERE */
        default:
                return NULL;
        }
        return e;
}
```

The code for `KE_STRING` and `KE_VOIDPTR` cases is identical except for the calculation of size in case of string.