# C++ While loop initiates too early

Tags: c++

I'm trying to imitate a while loop to count vowels in a set number of lines. The first input is the total about of lines to be entered. However this starts the loop and outputs a 0. This means it only counts 7 lines instead of 8. I could solve this by setting count to -1 however it would still output the random zero. Is there a way I can change to loop to account for this?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstring>
using namespace std;


int main() {

    string sentence;
    int count;
    int total;
    int length;
    int lengthcount;
    int output;
    output = 0;
    length = 0;
    count = 0;
    total = 0;
    lengthcount = 0;
    cin >> total;

    while (total != count){
        getline(cin, sentence);
        length = sentence.length();
        while (length != lengthcount){
            switch(sentence[lengthcount]){
                case 'a':
                    ++output;
                    break;
                case 'e':
                    ++output;
                    break;
                case 'i':
                    ++output;
                    break;
                case 'o':
                    ++output;
                    break;
                case 'u':
                    ++output; 
                    break;
                case 'y':
                    ++output;
                    break;

            }
            ++lengthcount;
        }
        cout << output << " ";
        ++count;
        lengthcount = 0;
        output = 0;
    }

return 0;
}
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8146106/does-case-switch-work-like-this will help you simplify your code.

Answer (score 2):

You can read the number of lines just as you read the lines themselves.

```
string totalstring;
getline(cin, totalstring);    
total = stoi(totalstring);
```

This way, the newline character will be consumed.

Comment: Where would I add that? Also what does stoi do?

Comment: You can replace `cin >> total;` with this. `stoi` is just string to integer.