# Use Windows Semaphores to synchronize Windows File Mappings

Tags: c, winapi

I want to use Windows Semaphores to add synchronization to a Windows File Mapping. So, one process creates the file mapping and another (perhaps multiple other processes) can come in and access the data that is shared. Can anyone give a suggestion as to how this can be done. I have done the following:

In the process that creates the file mapping, I have used `CreateSemaphore` and specified a name. In another process that attempts to access the data, I use `OpenSemaphore` to get a handle to the created sempahore, then I call `WaitForSingleObject`, I then switch on this value, and if its `WAIT_OBJECT0`, I perform the work, and finally calling `ReleaseSemaphore` once the work is done.
I am doing this in C, using a JNI shared library.

The problem is that it simply goes into the default case. Is there anything else that I should do, or am I missing something?

I'm pretty new to how Windows sems work, and I cannot find a concrete example 
of how they work between multiple processes (no threads). If anyone can give any suggestions, It would be much appreciated.

Here is some code:

**Create the file mapping**

```
// create the semaphore here
semaphore = CreateSemaphore(
  NULL,
  10,
  10,
  SEMAPHORE_NAME
);

// some semaphore error checking
if (semaphore == NULL) {
  printf("Error occured creating semaphore %d\n", GetLastError());
  return -1;
}

//create mapping object
mappedFileHandle = CreateFileMapping (
  INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE,
  NULL,
  PAGE_READWRITE,
  0,
  BUFFER_SIZE,
  MEMORY_MAPPING_NAME
);

if (mappedFileHandle == NULL) {
  printf("Error creating a mapped file: %d", GetLastError());
  return -1;
}

// map view of a file into address space of a calling process
buffer = (LPCTSTR) MapViewOfFile (
  mappedFileHandle,
  FILE_MAP_ALL_ACCESS,
  0,
  0,
  BUFFER_SIZE
);

if (buffer == NULL) {
  printf("Could not map view");
  CloseHandle(mappedFileHandle);
  return -1;
}

CopyMemory(buffer, str, (_tcslen(str) * sizeof(TCHAR))); // problem!!
UnmapViewOfFile(buffer);
CloseHandle(mappedFileHandle);
//  CloseHandle(semaphore);
```

**Process code that gets the data**

```
// try open the semahore
semaphore = OpenSemaphore (
  SEMAPHORE_ALL_ACCESS,
  NULL,
  SEMAPHORE_NAME
);

// some error checking
if (semaphore == NULL) {
  printf("Could not open semaphore %d\n", GetLastError());
  return -1;
}

waitResult = WaitForSingleObject(
  semaphore,
  -1 // block
);

// try to open the file mapping -- SHOULD BE DONE ATOMICALLY
// ======================================================================

switch (waitResult) {
  case WAIT_OBJECT_0:
          printf("Got in wait_result0");
          mappedFileHandle = OpenFileMapping (
            FILE_MAP_ALL_ACCESS,
            FALSE,
            MEMORY_MAPPING_NAME
          );

          if (mappedFileHandle == NULL) {
            printf("Could not open file mapping");
            return errorForJavaProgram;
          }

          // read data here, must be a critical region

          buffer = (LPTSTR) MapViewOfFile(
            mappedFileHandle,
            FILE_MAP_ALL_ACCESS,
            0,
            0,
            BUFFER_SIZE
          );

          if (buffer == NULL) {
            printf("Could not map view");
            CloseHandle(mappedFileHandle);
            return errorForJavaProgram;
          }

          message = (*env)->NewStringUTF(env, buffer);

          if (!ReleaseSemaphore(semaphore, 1, NULL)) {
            printf("An error occured releasing the semaphore: %d\n", GetLastError());
            return -1;
          }
    default:
      printf("Got to default \n");
} //switch
```

Comment: What is your question? It sounds like you are already doing what you need to do. Of course we can't be sure because you only described your code. File mappings for IPC isn't exactly easy. Are you sure you chose the right tool for the job.

Comment: You would probably be better off using a [mutex](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms684266(v=vs.85).aspx) (only one thread at a time) or a read-write lock (either one writer or multiple readers, the inbuilt one is limited to in-process, but one can be built with a mutex and a semaphore). Using a semaphore you'll end up emulating one of the others.

Comment: I realised question was vague. Edited question and added code.

Comment: What value does `waitResult` have? What are `SEMAPHORE_NAME` and  `MEMORY_MAPPING_NAME`? Why did you choose to use a semaphore? Why did you opt for file mapping rather than higher level IPC mechanisms?

Comment: Your semaphore doesn't guard against concurrent reads and writes. As long as no more than 9 threads are reading, the writer can obtain the semaphore as well, and thrash the memory.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan `waitResult` is zero. `SEMAPHORE_NAME` is a defined constant used to name the semaphore. `MEMORY_MAPPING_NAME` is also a constant that names the mapping, used in `CreateFileMapping`. I believe file mapping offers better performance (correct me if im wrong) than higher level IPC mechanisms.

Comment: Clearly they are constants. I was wondering what value they had though. Whether you used local or global namespace. You know that `WAIT_OBJECT_0` has value `0`? So you are executing the `WAIT_OBJECT_0` case and the `default` case. You are victim of switch fall through. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8146106/does-case-switch-work-like-this  That's the simple answer to your question. That a semaphore seems like the wrong choice remains. I think there are many problems with your code. I would be surprised if memory maps were the best choice for you.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan You say I have many problems.. what are said problems if I can ask?

Comment: Start with the maximum count of 10. Why a semaphore? Why not a mutex? But I'm just repeating what has been stated above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your switch statement is subject to fall through. For one of the many discussions that can be found here on Stack Overflow, see [Does case-switch work like this?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8146106/does-case-switch-work-like-this).

Your code executes the `WAIT_OBJECT_0` and then simply continues to the `default` case. You need to add a `break` or a `return` at the very end of the `WAIT_OBJECT_0` case.