# Switch statement is NOT converting char input to string output

Tags: c++

```
char carInsuranceCode;

string getCarInsuranceCode; 

string CarInsuranceInformation::getCarInsuranceCode(char carInsuranceCode)
{
    switch(carInsuranceCode)
    {
        case '1':  cout << "AllState";
        case '2':  cout << "Geico";
        case '3':  cout << "StateFarm";
        case '4':  cout << "E-Insureance"; 
        default:   cout << "Other";
        break;                           
    }

}

void CarInsuranceInformation::printCarInsuranceInformation(void)
{
    cout << "- - - - CAR INSURANCE INFORMATION - - - "     << endl;
    cout << "Insurance Code: "<< getCarInsuranceCode()     << endl;
}
```

This is being done in a header file and will not cout into the printCarInsuranceInformation. The char is said to not want to convert to a string in the switch statement. The assignment is mandatory to convert the char input into the specified out of the string.

Thank You.

Comment: Just a heads up! The current code will have [case fall-through](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8146106/does-case-switch-work-like-this).

Comment: @Obicere Yes, it needs to cout. For example, if the user is to input 1 as their carInsuranceCode, the output should say:

Comment: - - - CAR INSURANCE INFORMATION - - -

Comment: Insurance Code: AllState

Answer (score 1):

The `getCarInsuranceCode` could be implemented one of two ways:

1) It could return the insurer, and the code that calls it would be responsible for outputting it.

2) It can output the insurer, and the code that calls it should not attempt to output it.

It seems you did half of one and half of the other -- that won't work.

Maybe this is what you wanted, using option 1:

```
string CarInsuranceInformation::getCarInsuranceCode(char carInsuranceCode)
{
     switch(carInsuranceCode)
      {
        case '1':  return "AllState";
        case '2':  return "Geico";
        case '3':  return "StateFarm";
        case '4':  return "E-Insureance"; 
        default:   return "Other";
      }
 }
```

Comment: All I need it to do is take the input (1, 2 , 3, or 4) and output the insurer. Although, it will not convert the char to a string. How can I do this?

Comment: @HelpMePlease123 Either of the two ways I explained in my answer. Do you see that you need to pick one of those two ways? Do you see that you didn't do that in the code you pasted above?

Comment: @DavidSchwarts 1) It could return the insurer, and the code that calls it would be responsible for outputting it. <-- How would I be able to implement this one then?

Comment: @HelpMePlease123 See update to my answer. In that case, there should not be a `cout <<` inside `getCarInsuranceCode`.

Comment: @DavidSchwarts I implemented the returns instead and got this error: PTIns.h:51:9: error: prototype for 'std::string CarInsuranceInformation::getCarInsuranceCode(char)' does not match any in class 'CarInsuranceInformation

Comment: @HelpMePlease123 You have bugs in other parts of the code then, so find them and fix them. The error message tells you exactly what the problem is. Also, get rid of `string getCarInsuranceCode;`, having a string with the same name as a class member function is just going to cause confusion.

Comment: ignore the 1 or 2 case. Just use the code shown here - it is correct. If it does not compile they show all your code and the error in the question

Answer (score 0):

From what you've given, this code should not compile.

1. As @David Schwartz said, `return` instead of `cout` is needed.
2. your call to `getCarInsuranceCode()` has no argument.