# Switch in C++ hits everything?

Tags: c++

**First of all, I know breaks fix this issue, but I just want to make sure I understand the default behavior of a switch in C++.**

I have the following C++ code that isn't working the way I think it would coming from other languages:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main(){
    int n;
    cin >> n;
    switch(n) {
    case 1: cout << "one" << endl;
    case 2: cout << "two" << endl;
    case 3: cout << "three" << endl;
    case 4: cout << "four" << endl;
    case 5: cout << "five" << endl;
    case 6: cout << "six" << endl;
    case 7: cout << "seven" << endl;
    case 8: cout << "eight" << endl;
    case 9: cout << "nine" << endl;
    default: cout << "Greater than 9" << endl;
    }
    // your code goes here
    return 0;
}
```

Which outputs:

```
$ ./a.out 
1
one
two
three
four
five
six
seven
eight
nine
Greater than 9
```

Why are the other cases being hit?

Why is the default behavior different from other languages?

Comment: you need to use `break`, otherwise the `case`s fall through (which is useful in some scenarios)

Comment: what if `n` is negative? For any negative value, your code will display **Greater than 9**

Comment: Java requires breaks. What language are you saying doesn't need breaks?

Comment: By the way, which *"other languages"* are you referring to? Java `switch` behaves the same and in C# it would be a compile-time error (unless the `case` is completely empty)

Comment: See [Duff's Device](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Duff%27s_device) for why this behaviour can be helpful.

Comment: "Why are the other cases being hit?" Because that's how `switch` works in C++. A `case` without a `break` falls through to the next `case`. Just the way the language works.

Comment: See also; [How to Get Fired Using Switch Statements & Statement Expressions](http://blog.robertelder.org/switch-statements-statement-expressions/) .

Comment: "default: cout << "Greater than 9"" not really. It *might* be greater, but it might also be less than `1`.

Comment: This is what you are looking for  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8146106/does-case-switch-work-like-this

Answer (score 3):

In C++, the switch statement supports something called "fall-through". This means that once one case statement has gone through and does not have a `break` associated with it, the code will "fall-through" to the next case and run that part too, until a `break` stops it or the `switch` ends. This means, to get your desired behaviour you have to add `break` to all of your case statements:

```
case 1: cout << "one" << endl; break;
case 2: cout << "two" << endl; break;
case 3: cout << "three" << endl; break;
case 4: cout << "four" << endl; break;
case 5: cout << "five" << endl; break;
case 6: cout << "six" << endl; break;
case 7: cout << "seven" << endl; break;
case 8: cout << "eight" << endl; break;
case 9: cout << "nine" << endl; break;
default: cout << "Greater than 9" << endl; break; // not required but good practice.
```

Answer (score 1):

This is normal. `switch` in C/C++ (and many other C-like languages) fall through their `case` statements, from one to the next to the next until the very end.

If you don't want this (and let's be honest, almost nobody does), you need to add a `break` at the end of every `case` statement.

Comment: Though in your case I'd just use `n` as an index in a `static` string array.